# Error while using numpy random.normalvariate()

Tags: python, numpy, random

I tried to generate random `probs` by using the following line code:

```
probs = [np.clip(random.normalvariate(0.1, 0.05), 0, 1) for x in range(1000)]
```

Unexpectedly I faced the following error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'normalvariate'
```

Any idea how to solve this? I checked out the docs I find that this attribute exists in the `numpy.random` however it doesn't work when I used it in above code.

Any help to fix this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: If you want a normal distribution, I think random.normal(0.1, 0.05) is what you need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that you make confusion between `random` module whose documenttion is : https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/random.html

And `random` sub-module that belongs to `numpy`, its documentation can be found here https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html

**Error origin**

It seems that you imported `numpy.random` and you tried to use `normalvariate` while the latter function belongs to `random` module.

**Solution**

So to solve the issue write the following `import`:

```
import random

probs = [np.clip(random.normalvariate(0.1, 0.05), 0, 1) for x in range(1000)]
```

Output:

```
[0.10399310517618868,
 0.10416076922742254,
 0.10683877729386676,
 0.14789317007499886,
 0.11551976284566698,
...
```